# Jquery validation event after errors are shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using this plugin
http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

What I am trying to do is to manipulate the error message's element after the the validation is done. But, using this code

```
$(".selector").validate({
  errorClass: 'error-message'
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
       console.log($("#myDiv").find('.error-message').length); 
  }
});
```

outputs 0, as I am guessing because this function works before outputting error messages into html. How can I run my code after validation is done and also error div elements are already inserted into page.

**update**

`myDiv` element is a div of a specific input, not for the whole form, I want to call a function that will move the error element at the end of that div (I have another elements in my div) simply it would look smth like this

```
if ($("#myDiv").find('.error-message').length > 0) {
   $("#myDiv").find('.error-message').appendTo($("#myDiv"));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this may you want to this

```
if(! $(".selector").valid())
{
   console.log($("#myDiv").find('.error-message').length); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    console.log($("#myDiv").find('.error-message').length); 
}
```

You are correct.  It's simply a timing issue where this fires just before the messages are displayed.  Unless error messages are already displayed when you click the button, this method will fail.

However, I'm not sure why you're asking how to count the error messages like that when there already exists a built-in method as per [the example in the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler).

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();  // reports the number of errors
    console.log(errors); 
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nv282zom/**

FWIW, there is also a flaw in your code as you're only counting the elements with the error class.  [This will always give you double the number of elements](http://jsfiddle.net/nv282zom/1/) as the error class is applied to both the input element and the error message.

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"What I am trying to do is to manipulate the error message's element after the the validation is done."*

However, you've only shown us that you wanted to count them.  There are lots of other callback functions and options that can be used for error message manipulation... just explain exactly what you want.